# my node forever plug-in does not work

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I want to run my node.js server with node forever, I installed the plug-in node forever, but after closing my putty console the node.js server is closed. What can I do?

I tried these commands:

```
forever -m 5 myserver.js

forver myserver.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct command is:

```
forever start myserver.js
```

See more in help

```
usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
forever -h // to see help
```

See runnig processes

```
forever list
```